# What is the correct image size for iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: xcode6, iphone-6-plus

I suppose iPhone 6 Plus is with 1242x2208px. Thus, my @3x images are scaled according to this ratio.
When applied, the image is much bigger than it's displayed on iPhone 6 and iPhone 5 with corresponding @2x images. I wonder why?

below is an example - the last icon is using @3x while the first three are stretched from @2x images.

[image]

Comment: Where do you get `1242x2208px`? It's `1080x1920px` for iPhone 6 Plus. See [this](http://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_6_plus-6665.php)

Comment: But it's said 1080 is actual size and Apple auto downscaled from 1242 to 1080?

Comment: @Raptor in xcode 6 iphone 5.5 inch size in interface builder 414x736, what @3 gives 1242x2208. Suggested size for launch image is also 1242x2208.

Comment: @nyekimov so why my image looks bigger?

Answer (score 0):

After being struggling for days, I finally found the problem.

It turns out that, you have to set LaunchImage sets to fit each device screen appropriately. Otherwise, Apple will assume your app is not ready for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus yet, thus stretching your image assets to fit the screen. So even when I set the high resolution images, it still recognise it is for iPhone 5S and below.

The solution is, create a LaunchImage asset catalog, make sure you have the right resolution of launch images for each device. for iPhone 6 and 6 plus, you these additional assets:

Default-667h@2x.png - 750 x 1334

Default-736h@3x.png - 1242 x 2208

Default-736h-Landscape@3x.png - 2208 x 1242

And then, in your project setting > General > App Icons and Launch Images, make sure you are using asset catalog and choose the correct LaunchImage set.

Hope this helps.

Note that this probably only bothers those who are not using Storyboard but pure code to manage UI.

Additional Note: I encountered cache problem with Xcode 6 and simulator. When you update image and it doesn't take effect, try goto Simulator > Reset Content and Settings OR in your Xcode press cmd + alt + shift + K